# Can Host and Run website in subdirectory independent with parent website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have issue and i want to know whether this solution is right. 
For example i have a root website in MVC and Can i run other website host inside a diretory of this root website. I mean:

```
Root website
  - css files
  - js files
  - other sources
  - **website1**
    + css files website1
    + js files website1
    + other sources website1
  - **website2**
    + css files website2
    + js files website2
    + other sources website2
```

In my root website have a link like:

**mydomain.com/template/website1** or **mydomain.com/template/website2**

And user can operate on website1 and website2 independently with parent website.

I just wonder whether i can do that. In the past i have multiple template website and i host in separate subdomain. Is there any ways better the way that i doing now?

Please give me some guide and i will appriciate anyone help me. 
My english not good, Let ask for me if you cann't understand my idea! Thanks.